# F# - A period in a union case name

Tags: f#

I want to have a union case name like the following

```
type PrimaryDiagnosisSite =
    | ``C00.0 - External upper lip``
```

Unfortunately, the compiler complains about the period in the name:

```
Invalid namespace, module, type or union case name
```

I'd like to keep the period in the union case name, if possible. The compiler doesn't like when I try to escape the period via backslash.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible, it seems.

From the [F# language spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf), section 3.4:

> Note that when an identifier is
> used for the name of a types, union type case, module, or namespace, the following characters are
> not allowed even inside double-backtick marks:
> ‘.', '+', '$', '&', '[', ']', '/', '\', '*', '"', '`'